# IBM System i Access causes web application not to load

Tags: mysql, virtual-server

I have an web application that was developed in Visual Studio 13 using Visual Basic. When I switched it over to a virtual server to run, it was ran fine until I installed IBM System i Access. It was needed to connect to a db2 database. After its installation, removing it causes the application to stop working. It tries to load, but never does. After uninstalling it, the program worked fine, but I need it for the application. Do you have any idea of what may fix it?

Things to note:

MySQL is installed on the same virtual server as well, but uninstalling MySQL components didn't cause it to work.

Its ran using .NET 4.0

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the problem was due to the .NET Framework I was running. My application uses .NET 4.0. This was an issue because the version(6.1) of IBM System i Access for Windows only works with .NET 2.0. Hopes this helps someone eventually.